# Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have no experience working with Lightning components and have been working with classic for a while now, where I do have experience working with AngularjS as front-end language,

I have just started studying lightning web components to get started. Is it a good idea to directly start with LWC?

If yes, what are some of the best resources to ramp up the learning process and if there are certain use cases that you can point me to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Trailhead should always be your G2 place for anything Salesforce related. Additionally, the [LWC documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_javascript_methods) is also worthwhile and would definitelly recommend reading through to get familair with the api's, usage, and generally speaking, has all you need to know to develop with them.

Comment: To my opinion, yes you can start with Lightning Web Components directly. This new framework is based on web standards like other frameworks like Angular or React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can start LWC directly I will say its better to start it directly. Definitely trailhead is the place you see bit you can also try developerforce documentation from top to bottom and we are here to help you.

As well as there are good videos on youtube. I personally brought the  mannish  chowdhury code on Udamy its quite to get a quick grasp.

Try to install the lwc recipes from trailhead and go through each of them.